# how do I add behavior to jackson's default deserialization?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have three classes:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CaseBO.class, name = "case"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CallBO.class, name = "call"),
})
abstract class BusinessObject {
     private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
     private String type;

     public String getType() {
         return this.type;
     }

     public void setType(String type) {
         this.type = type;
     }

     public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}

class CallBO extends BusinessObject {
   private String content;
   public String getContent() {
       return this.content;
   }
   public void setContent(String content) {
       this.content = content;
   }
}

class CaseBo extends BusinessObject {
    private String caseId;
    public String getCaseId() {
        return caseId;
    }
    public void setCaseId(String caseId) {
        this.caseId = caseId;
    }
}
```

What I want is:

besides default inheritance deserialization which put json fields and their values into POJO's bean properties, I want to put every fields into properties map. So how can I do this with minimum code?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why u wanna put fields in derived classes into properties? CallBO and CaseBO are for separating their unique params so as not to interfere with each other, so why putting them altogether again?

Comment: For business logic, property changes frequently, I have to put them into a container